# Count documents of certain type (filter against user before)

Tags: couchdb, mapreduce

Documents (pseudo, rev and id omitted):

```
{
   "type": 1,
   "username": "aron",
   "data": { ... }
}
{
   "type": 1,
   "username": "bob",
   "data": { ... }
}
{
   "type": 1,
   "username": "steve",
   "data": { ... }
}
{
   "type": 1,
   "username": "steve",
   "data": { ... }
}
{
   "type": 2,
   "username": "steve",
   "data": { ... }
}
{
   "type": 3,
   "username": "steve",
   "data": { ... }
}
{
   "type": 3,
   "username": "steve",
   "data": { ... }
}
{
   "type": 3,
   "username": "steve",
   "data": { ... }
}
```

I want to know, how many documents of type 1/2/3 steve has.

View:

```
count: {
    map: function (doc) { 
        emit([doc.username, doc.type], 1);  
    }
    reduce: function (key, values, rereduce) {
        return sum(values);
    }
}
```

Now I request

```
/database/_design/myDesign/_view/count?key=["steve",1] // result: 2
/database/_design/myDesign/_view/count?key=["steve",2] // result: 1
/database/_design/myDesign/_view/count?key=["steve",3] // result: 3
```

This **works perfectly well**.

To smart things up, I was wondering if I can query that in one view?

Is there a way to count the number of documents of unknown number of types in one view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can perform a range query to achieve this:

```
.../count?startkey=["steve",1]&endkey=["steve",3]&group=true&reduce=true
```

This will fetch one line for every key between `["steve",1]` and `["steve",3]` inclusive. You can adjust values `0` and `3` according to what your types can actually be. For instance, if your types can be any scalar value, you can use `["steve",null]` and `["steve",{}]` as the range boundaries.

Comment: +1 Good point about finding *all* of Steve's types. Once there are hundreds or thousands of types this may be a problem; but I suspect in the real application that there are manageably few.

Answer (score 6):

You can POST to your view with a body like this;

```
{"keys":[["steve",1], ["steve",2]]}
```

Also, try using "_sum" as your reduce function, it will run natively in Erlang and should be several times faster than doing it in Javascript.

Comment: Sure, but people often like to get a 2x+ performance improvement for free. :P